# calculating attention scores in Bahdanau attention in tensorflow using decoder hidden state and encoder output

Tags: tensorflow, keras, attention-model, logits

This question relates to the neural machine translation shown here: [Neural Machine Translation](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/text/nmt_with_attention)

`self.W1` and `self.W2` are initialized to dense neural layers of 10 units each, in lines 4 and 5 in the `__init__` function of `class BahdanauAttention`

In the code image attached, I am not sure I understand the feed forward neural network set up in line 17 and line 18. So, I broke this formula down into it's parts. See line 23 and line 24.

`query_with_time_axis` is the input tensor to `self.W1` and `values` is input to `self.W2`. And each compute the function `Z = WX + b`, and the Z's are added together. The dimensions of the tensors added together are `(64, 1, 10)` and `(64, 16, 10)`. I am assuming random weight initialization for both `self.W1` and `self.W2` is handled by `Keras` behind the scenes.

**Question:**

After adding the Z's together, a non-linearity (`tanh`) is applied to come up with an activation and this resulting activation is input to the next layer `self.V`, which is a layer with just one output and gives us the `score`.

For this last step, we don't apply an activation function (tanh etc) to the result of `self.V(tf.nn.tanh(self.W1(query_with_time_axis) + self.W2(values)))`, to get a single output from this last neural network layer.

Is there a reason why an activation function was not used for this last step?

[image: See line 17, 18, 23 and 24]

Comment: Please consider pasting the code as plain text, so it is better searchable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ouput of the attention form so-called attention *energies*, i.e., one scalar for each encoder output. These numbers get stacked into a vector a this vector is normalized using softmax, yielding attention *distribution*.

So, in fact, there is non-linearity applied in the next step, which is the softmax. If you used an activation function before the softmax, you would only decrease the space of distributions that the softmax can do.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, separated by the `print` statements. I was just too focused on looking for the outermost activation on the same line that computes the `score`.                                                             Can you please comment some more on your point regarding how using an activation before `softmax` would decrease the space of distributions that the `softmax` can do (although I don't think it would make sense to use activation function right after already having applied an activation function)..